# Страницы не открываются MODX Revo

Tags: modx

Проблема в том, что кромк главной страницы ничего из контента сайта не отображается, открываю любую страницу и вместо нее выводится такое сообщение:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@thekey.hopesh.ru and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Что делать уже не знаю. Вот ссылка, если что: http://dev.hopesh.ru

Comment: Сама страница с _"500 Internal Server Error"_ мало о чем говорит. Смотрите логи сервера, на что ругается при обращении с "внутренним" страницам.

Comment: 1)  Очистить кеш - `Управление` / `Очистить кеш`. 2) Включите максимально подробный вывод в логи - `Системные Настройки` /  ключ `debug` установить в `1`. 3) Смотреть причину 500 ошибки в журнале ошибок - `/manager/?a=system/event`

Comment: Люди, спасибо за обратную связь, забыл написать, что нашел вчера проблему. В .htaccess путь к папке с файлами сайта был неправильно прописан